# Redirection does not take effect

Tags: javascript, ajax

In one of my projects, I have `window.location.href='index.php'`. That project is big and it is absurd to paste whole code.

In it I have attached event handlers, some AJAX calls and few custom animations. I had solved this in other manner, but I would appreciated few suggestions why that command didn't work?

When I used FireBug to inspect code, and go step by step, redirection was successful.

Comment: You say that in Firebug, the redirection was successful, so what doesn't work?

Comment: In normal flow, without inspecting, it does not redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your code to the `onload` handler or, if you use jQuery, in the ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.location.href='index.php';
});
```